# rotate a video on iPhone using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone

I'm using a MPMoviePlayerController to play a video on iPhone, I added its view to the app's window, but I rotate the simulator the video does not rotate.  What did I miss?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the video remains stationary, so if you rotate the device 180°, the video appears upside down in relation to the UI?

Comment: Yes, the video stays in portrait mode all the time

Comment: That seems to be an issue with iOS itself, since I just tested on both my iPad and iPhone that it rotates with the app, so long as the top UIViewController (or subclass, like a UINavigationController) allows rotation by responding to yes to `ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Comment: I tried subclassing UIViewController and adding the video to that, still doesn't work in the simulator, I don't have a device with me right now, mabye its a problem with the simulator?

Comment: That could very well be true. The iOS simulator only simulates iOS, not the underlying hardware, so there's a chance it uses QuickTime for this, and doesn't rotate the QuickTime view or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)press<p>
{<p>
<t> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/defaultscreenvideos.mp4"];<p>
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];<p>
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];<p>
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];<p>
    [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];<p>
    [[mp moviePlayer] repeatMode];<p>
    [[mp moviePlayer] setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];<p>
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];<p>
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];<p>
}

-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {       
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated]; <p>}
```

Comment: you didn't taken my last comment seriously,did you?